# Emacs psc-ide major mode, error finding output directory

Tags: purescript

I just tried installing psc-ide mode, along with the purescript major mode. I'm using emacs 25.3.1 on a Mac.

I am following the "Purescript by Example" book. I created a project in

`/users/Mike/Dropbox/purescript/proj01/`

I run emacs. I then try to start the server. I enter the above as my project directory (I deleted the `src` final directory that it provided). I then get this error:

"Error in process sentinel: cannot locate your output directory"

I checked in the customization section what "psc ide output directory" is set to, and it's "output/"

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if there is no `./output` directory in your project and can be resolved by simply running `pulp build`. In your case the directory would then be `/users/Mike/Dropbox/purescript/proj01/output`.

Before running `pulp build` you might need to run `npm install` and `bower install` or `psc-package install` to get the project dependencies.